# getSurfaceTexture() returning null

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view_with_buttons_on = factory.inflate(R.layout.buts, null);
view_with_buttons_on.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

game_frame_layout = new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());
surface_view_extension = new SurfaceViewExtension(getApplicationContext());
game_frame_layout.addView(surface_view_extension);
game_frame_layout.addView(view_with_buttons_on);

setContentView(game_frame_layout);

preview_texture_view = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.tex1);

try {
    camera.setPreviewTexture(preview_texture_view.getSurfaceTexture());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The layout buts.xml contains a set of buttons as well as a `TextureView` labelled `"@id/tex1"`.
It appears that `preview_texture_view.getSurfaceTexture()` is returning null. The documentation says:

> This method may return null if the view is not attached to a window or
>   if the surface texture has not been initialized yet.

I assume the surface must already be attached to a window because the buttons are visible, so I guess my mistake must be not having initialized preview_texture_view - but I have no idea what it means to "initialize" preview_texture_view other than what I have already done. I have seen some related sample code and can not figure out any initialization process.

**EDIT:** Maybe it takes a little time to attach to the window or the be initialized. Maybe I need to set up a callback for when its ready?.. just guessing.

Comment: where are you executing the getSurfaceTexture? It is on the onCreate method of your activity?

Comment: yes.... blah blah to make text long enough for SO to accept.

Comment: sorry, but I didn't understand your comment, can you explain yourself?

Comment: My answer was yes, it is in the onCreate method of my activity.

Comment: That is your problem, try to get the surface texture on the windows focus change and not in the onCreate, at this time the view isn't inflated (maybe)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved: My guess turned out to be correct. To fix, set up the following:

Make activity implement

```
TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener
```

add method `onSurfaceTextureAvailable()`

call

```
preview_texture_view.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @user1767754 what he says is that there is a listener for `TextureView` to know when the surface is available or not