# TextureView.getSurfaceTexture() returning null

Tags: android

I have a textureview in my layout file which I've attached to a service. My texture view is returning null pointer exception even after I have set the surface texture listener.

```
if (textureView != null) {
                final SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
               texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());
                previewSurface = new Surface(texture);

            }
```

The error i get is

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(int, int)' on a null object reference
        at com.sensennetworks.sentrack.Camera2Service.createCameraPreviewSession(Camera2Service.java:475)
```

I found this question asked already 
[getSurfaceTexture() returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735456/getsurfacetexture-returning-null)
which i already am doing.

I am referring this git repo https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make activity `implements` `TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener`

Add method

```
onSurfaceTextureAvailable()
```

Call by

```
textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
```